# Why is execve ignoring environment arguments?

Tags: c, path, environment-variables

Say we have program1:

```
int main(void) {
    char *env[2];

    env[0] = "PATH=/";
    env[1] = NULL;

    execve("/program2", NULL, env);

    exit(0);
}
```

We also have program2:

```
int main(void) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Debugging this, PATH isn't actually modified in the new process (program2) that is executed.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal runnable example that demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Besides the fact that you do not follow the warning that you shall not pass `NULL` as second argument to functions of  the `exec*()`  family, but a `NULL`-terminated array of pointers to `char` (just like `env`), the code is ok and works here.

Comment: Do you know whether the `execve()` is working at all?  Your first program should have `return(1);` or `exit(1);` at the end, and print a diagnostic in case `execve()` returns (if it returns, you know it failed).  Wouldn't you do better `/usr/bin/env` so you get to see the new process's environment?

Comment: execve() is definitely working. I'm not completely sure what env does for me here (or how to use it in C), but note that I do not have access to the second program.

Comment: In *program1*, your code attempts to execute *program2*, which is supposed to be located at the root of the file system tree (`"/program2"` in your code). Why would you place that program there? Do you somehow want *program1* to think that *program2* is there by updating the `PATH` environment variable like you do?

Answer (score 0):

> Debugging this, PATH isn't actually modified in the new process
>   (program2) that is executed.

This is not true. Note that `p environ` doesn't work, while `x 0x8049650` (address `environ@@GLIBC_2.0`, obtained from `info var environ`) does:

```
(gdb) p environ
$1 = (char **) 0x0
(gdb) p/x &environ
$2 = 0xf7fbfd44
(gdb) x 0x8049650
0x8049650 : 0xffffdf18
(gdb) x/s **0x8049650
0xffffdfe8:      "PATH=/"
```